# How do I join information schema to the table's data?

Tags: mysql, join, information-schema

I need to join a table using it's column name from the INFORMATION SCHEMA. Is this possible?

I actually found another way to work around it. I am using Innodb. For the structure it's kind of complicated, but this is the query I was working with :

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            ct.field_name, 
            ct.length, 
            ct.description, 
            IFNULL( mfc.hide, ct.hide) as hide, 
            IFNULL(mfc.required, ct.required) as required, 
            ct.example  
        FROM xxxxxx.config_marketplace ct  
        LEFT JOIN xxxxx.merchant_field_config mfc  
            ON mfc.field_id = ct.id 
            AND mfc.industry = 'MP' 
            AND mfc.merchant_id = '1512MP5'
    ) as t 
    WHERE hide != 'Y'
) b 
ON LOWER(b.field_name) = c.COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE 
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'XXXXX_1512MP5' 
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = 'marketplace_custom';
```

Basically, config_marketplace holds the default configuration of the field names(column name) that will be shown, while merchant_field_config does the configurations of the fields I would like to hide based on each merchant's requirements. Lastly, marketplace_custom would be placed in the individual merchant's db with the column header which I would like to join to the data in that table.

PS. I know it's not a very good explanation.

Just out of curiosity, is this possible? I am working around it, but it will be a really good thing to know for future usage!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325773/generate-information-schema-table-for-mysql-database

Comment: can you explain more, like which columns and of which tables?

Comment: Information schema are not base tables but views. You can still join them though, just like any other table or view.

Comment: I would suggest that having a column contain a "column name" is bad schema design.  Please describe what you need to do, not the attempted solution.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... ) WHERE ...` --> `SELECT ... HAVING ...`

Answer (score -1):

That depends upon the type of DB you actually use.

In NOSQL like MongoDB support Dynamic schemas to join the table using column name which results in embedded documents.

Comment: Hey Anan thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, i am using InnoDB. Cheers!